# Is $C_c^\infty$ dense in $H^{s,p}$ even if $s < 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

It is easy to show that $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is dense in $H^{s, p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p \in (1, \infty)$, where $H^{s,p}$ are Sobolev spaces (or Bessel potential spaces).

I know that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is dense in $H^{s,p}$ if $s \geq 0$, since $C_c^\infty \hookrightarrow W^{n,p} = H^{n,p} \hookrightarrow H^{s,p}$, where $\hookrightarrow$ is dense embedding and $s \leq n \in \mathbb{N}$.

However, is $C_c^\infty$ dense in $H^{s,p}$ even if $s < 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is, at least for $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$ which is what you'd call $H^{s, 2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ , but I can't think of any useful reference right now.

Comment: Bahouri, Chemin, Danchin: "Fourier analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations"  gives a (terse imo) proof of density for homogeneous Besov spaces (Proposition 2.74)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this is clear, because $\mathcal{D} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{S} \hookrightarrow H^{s,p}$, where $\hookrightarrow$ is dense embedding.